# Compare a enum type in a If

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

I'm having problems comparing a enum type.

This is my enum:

```
    enum typeson {folder, service};
    enum typeson *type;
```

And I have one method on my class that return the method type.

```
-(void) setType: (enum typeson) t;
-(enum typeson) getType;
```

And if I do this, it works:

```
NSLog(@"Object type: %d", [[[actualNode sons] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] getType]);
```

It returns 1 or 0 depends on the type. The problem is when I do this:

```
if (![[[actualNode sons] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] getType]==service) {
    NSLog(@"This is a service type");
}
```

It doesn't work. I have tried to change 'service' for 1, '1'... nothing happens. Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason that you negate the result of the comparison to `service` and then you log out that the type (which is not "service") is indeed "service"?

Comment: Also note, that in Obj-C the convention is not to prefix getter methods with "get". Just use `- (enum typeson)type;`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I used to program in Java and to use gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//  this ! probably shouldn't be there.
//  v
if (![[[actualNode sons] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] getType]==service) {
    NSLog(@"This is a service type");
}
```

Comment: Yap, that's what I'm talking about.